# How to dump data with Neo4j.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, dump, neo4j.rb

I'm working on Rails project with Neo4j.rb and I have a very basic problem: I'd like to dump my data to file (and next load it back). Unfortunately I can't do this. I tried this command:

```
neo4j-admin dump --database=<database> --to=<destination-path>
```

but I got this:

> ```
> neo4j-admin: command not found
> ```

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you in the right user? You need to be in user `neo4j` to use neo4j-admin and your database must be stopped.

Comment: I even doesn't know what my password is. I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0P0pOP34Mw and there was no step with setting password for `neo4j` user.

Comment: PS: "neo4j" password doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem. We must run `neo4j-admin` script using its full path, what was in that case `db/neo4j/development/bin/neo4j-admin`. So, my final solution is:

```
db/neo4j/development/bin/neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=./my_dump
```

What's maybe important to add: I need my database stopped to do that. We can do this by running `rake neo4j:stop`, and then restart it by `rake neo4j:start`.